# How long after the interview will I receive the Schengen visa for Greece?

Tags: schengen-visas

I have submitted my application and done the biometrics on March 22. I have my interview on April 3. But I need my original passport before April 9, 2018 as I need to travel to Dubai on April 11, 2018.

I have attached a request letter and also the travel ticket to Dubai as proof so that they process my visa in priority and get it before April 9, 2018.

I want to know whether I will receive my visa and the passport before April 9, 2018 after that interview on April 3, so that I am able to travel to Dubai on April 11.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I got my Greek visa - from the Embassy in New Delhi immediately after the skype interview (which was just 2 days after submitting my application). Add a couple more days to courier. You can track each stage of the process online.